# using a non-network internet connection while being connected to a home network

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router, internet

So I've setup a home network using Netgear N300 router with the intention of connection my home computers together so that they can access files from each other...

The thing is, I don't want to connect to the internet using this router since I'm connecting to the internet via my cell phone's tethering/mobile hotspot wireless network capability

But then everytime I'm connected to the network, it wouldn't connect to my cellphone's internet connection and since the router is not connected to any modem (since I don't have any) I won't be able to get internet connection while being connected to the network even though my cellphone connection is connected...

Is there a way to resolve this such that I can both connect to my home network AND be able to connect to use the internet connection via my cellphone's mobile hotspot wireless network?

btw I'm using Windows 7

Answer (score 0):

You need a second wireless network card for the computer that will connect to both the phone's hotspot and the Netgear N300.  This would allow you to talk to the internet and the wireless LAN at the same time.  You can usually find a USB WiFi NIC for pretty cheap.

Comment: yea I'm already using cysco linksys AE1000 to connect to the Mobile Hotspot meanwhile I connect to the router using LAN cable...nonetheless when both the Mobile Hotspot and the Network is connected, it would not connect to the internet since it appears as if it's using the internet settings of the Netgear N300 instead of the connection to the mobile hotspot

Comment: In that case, have you tried changing the priority of the NICs?   http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/27994/how-to-change-the-priority-of-wiredwireless-network-cards-in-windows/